# Tick marks in background-image crashing ASP page

Tags: html, css, asp-classic

First off, I am debugging another programmer's code so I'm not entirely sure what he was attempting to do here. The class is already assigned a background-image. The previous programmer chose to overwrite that background-image with inline style. The line of code below was crashing the page until I took out the background-image. I'm assuming it's the double tick marks. Is it breaking some obscure CSS law that I don't know about?

```
ptobject = "<div id='ptObj' class='pttxtbox' style=""background-image:url('');"" onmousedown=""pregfocus(this, '', '');"" ></div>"

response.write ptobject
```

For reference, this is on a Classic ASP page that works just fine without the background-image.

Comment: Please describe "crash".  Generally a "crash" is characterized by the sudden and unexplained disappearance of an app.  Is this what you are experiencing?  Or are you getting a "hang" where the app freezes and appears unresponsive? Or are you getting an "error"?

Comment: Your code is not generating an ASP Classic of VBScript error. Like @AnthonyWJones said, could you describe 'crashing'?

Comment: Yes, I tested [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewTzq/) on many browsers, and as I suspected, `url('')` works just like `none` on all of them. Which I suspected is what the original programmer experienced too, otherwise they wouldn't have left it in. So I'm not sure what goes wrong now.

Comment: We're loading the ASP page this code is in as an include in a bigger ASP page via AJAX. The code I posted is not hit everytime this include is called (it's in a conditional). When it is hit, the include does not load at all and I receive an unspecified XML Error.

Answer (score 2):

If you're overwriting the style, you should use `background-image:none`. See [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background-properties).

`url('')` means that you're trying to load an image file from location `''`.
(I'd expect that to do nothing, but apparently, it causes a crash, so it's best not to!)

Comment: Thanks I realized the first part, the second was what I was curious about. Definitely stay way, but why?

Comment: @MadV No idea. Like I said above, I can't get `url('')`to crash. How does it crash exactly and on which browser?

Comment: I think that old browsers treated empty image source as request to the same page so probably same rule applies for background images - this means it tried to set the whole ASP page as the background image and thus got into infinite loop crashing the browser.

Comment: @MadV what browser? IE6 by any chance?

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's a good one, as I haven't been able to test that.

Comment: Cheers, found [this reference](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/) talking about empty image.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Heh, no definitely not IE6. We're using the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: @MadV so that's weird. Can you capture network traffic with the browser and see if you get into some loop, or some specific request cause the crash?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you have included this in the code example by accident `style=""background-image:url('');""` but it should be `style="background-image:url('');"` and `onmousedown=""pregfocus(this, '', '');""` should be `onmousedown="pregfocus(this, '', '');"` this might not be the cause of your problem but might help.

Comment: This is VBscript, where you write a quote in a string as a double quote. Classic ASP!

Comment: Double-double quotes in the way to escape double quotes in ASP Classic, VBScript.

Comment: And if you ask, how can you tell if this is VBscript and not Jscript? Well, Jscript would have `Response.Write` case sensitively.

Comment: That's fair enough, I was offering a piece of advise. I don't know ASP Classic syntax. Don't know if it deserved a down vote but there you go. Life goes on.

Comment: Should have mentioned this earlier. This is VBScript in Classic ASP,  where we're creating the HTML elements via a giant case statement (obviously not shown).

Comment: No you got me wrong I wasn't blaming anybody and it was tongue in cheek. There should definitely be some sort of <sarcasm> tag. That's the beauty of stackoverflow, people in the community have the right to up or down vote stuff they find inappropriate.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is the double "", this is an escape sequence but only when used with a string prefixed with @

so the line should read:

```
ptobject = @"<div id='ptObj' class='pttxtbox' style=""background-image:url('');"" onmousedown=""pregfocus(this, '', '');"" ></div>"
```

Hope that works

Martyn

Comment: This is VBscript, where you write a quote in a string as a double quote. Classic ASP!

Comment: Double-double quotes in the way to escape double quotes in ASP Classic, VBScript.

Comment: And if you ask, how can you tell if this is VBscript and not Jscript? Well, Jscript would have `Response.Write` case sensitively.